# QBRoomChatManager class not present in later Quickblox library - quickblox-sdk-release-2

Tags: android, quickblox, groupchat

Below link shows the latest documentation from Quickblox for Room Chat:

http://quickblox.com/developers/Chat#Group_chat

Code to integrate:

QBRoomChatManager roomChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getRoomChatManager();

But this class is **not present** in the latest library. Please help me on how to implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's

```
QBGroupChatManager groupChatManager = QBChatService.getInstance().getGroupChatManager();
```

Don't forget to check latest Android samples and snippets here

https://github.com/QuickBlox/quickblox-android-sdk